# Hide keyboard in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, keyboard, iphone-softkeyboard

Is there a way to make a UIWebView dismiss all associated input controls, such as keyboards/pickers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows])
    for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews])

        if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIFormAssistant"] == YES)
        {
            [keyboard removeFromSuperview];
        }
```

Dirty way but it works ;)

Answer (score 9):

Haven't tried it in a web view with a picker, but this definitely works to dismiss the keyboard:

```
[theWebView endEditing:YES];
```