# Dimiss keyboard when editing textfield on UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uitextfield

I'm opening a web page on UIWebview and this page has a textfield and a virtual keyboard the to enter password. But when edit the textfield iPhone virtual keyboard appears as well.
I wanted to dismiss iPhone keyboard and on the same time continue editing the textfield. I have tried the following but it did not work.

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.activeElement.blur()"];
```

And also tried to register for Keyboard notification so I can dimiss the keyboard but did not succeed. I would appreciate any ideas about how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector (keyboardDidShow:)
                                                 name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];



-(void) keyboardDidShow: (NSNotification *)notif 
{
// I want to dismiss the keyboard 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
[webView endEditing:YES]
```

You also can try this link if above solution does not work - [Hide keyboard in UIwebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385368/hide-keyboard-in-uiwebview)

Answer (score 2):

Add method that go over all the webview subviews and resign the first responder

```
     -(BOOL)resignFirstResponderAction:(UIView *)view{
        if (view.isFirstResponder){
            [view resignFirstResponder];
            return YES;
        }
        
        for (UIView *subView in view.subviews) {
            if ([self resignFirstResponderAction:subView]){
                return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
     }
```

then just call this method with the webview:

```
     [self resignFirstResponderAction:webView];
```

**Edit**

it seems there is much simpler solution:

```
[webView endEditing:YES]
```

I leave the original answer as it might help in some cases

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to take the focus away from the html element when it gets clicked like this:

```
 <input type="text" onClick="document.getElementById('myInput').blur();" id="myInput"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add next category of UIView to your code
And the method above to your implementation
Add the next code to your .m file, before the @implementation

```
@implementation UIView (FindFirstResponder)

- (UIView *)findFirstResponder
{
    if (self.isFirstResponder) {        
        return self;     
    }

    for (UIView *subView in self.subviews) {
        UIView *firstResponder = [subView findFirstResponder];

        if (firstResponder != nil) {
            return firstResponder;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
@end


-(void)hideWebViewFirstResponser{
    UIView *firstResponderOwner=[webView findFirstResponder];
    if(firstResponderOwner) {
        [firstResponderOwner resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```